# App Transport Security error for graph.facebook.com

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios9, sdwebimage

I'm trying to fetch a profile picture for a facebook user using this `SDWebImageDownloader` method:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?width=%@&height=%@", contact[USER_FACEBOOK_ID], @(width).stringValue, @(width).stringValue]];

SDWebImageDownloader *downloader = [SDWebImageDownloader sharedDownloader];

[downloader downloadImageWithURL:url options:0 progress:nil completed:^(UIImage *image, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL finished) {

    if (image) {
        [(UIButton *)view setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
}];
```

And even though I've followed every step from [this guide from Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9), for some reason I'm still getting this weird error:

```
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://graph.facebook.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/picture?width=450&height=450, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://graph.facebook.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/picture?width=450&height=450, NSLocalizedDescription=The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.
```

Comment: So have you tried simply making that URL into an HTTPS one?

Comment: No. But I believe adding this key `<key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key><true/>` to the app-Info.plist under `facebook.com` domain exception resolved the problem.

Comment: Thanks it works for me @artooras